# How to update the data from textbox to ms access

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access

now i trying web based appliaction please let me know, how to update the data from textbox to database(MS-ACCESS) using java code

1.jsp

In this jsp page i get the User name from the user and it is inserted to the database(ms-access).

2.jsp

In this jsp file agencyname and pid have to be updated to the database nearer to name field.This two values are in the textbox.

**2.jsp CODE**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,javax.servlet.*,java.sql.*,java.util.*" %> 

 try 
   {
        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        int pid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("update userdetail set agencyname ='"+agencyname+"',pid= '"+pid+"' where name='"+name+"'");
   }
 catch(Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

how could I perform that ????

Comment: What is meant by `1.jsp` and `2.jsp`?

Comment: jsp page 1,2 is jsp page name

Comment: It seems like you need a connection to MS Access.  Is that your question?

Comment: @Smandoli no i make coonection with database but agencyname and pid values are in the textbox that has to be updated to the database

Comment: How to retrive the textbox value and add to the database

Answer (score 1):

First add data source

```
Control panel-> Administrative Tools->Data Sources->Add->Microsoft Access Drivers(*mdb,*accdb)
```

Write connection URL like this.

```
 String URL="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb)};DBQ="+yourdbfile+".accdb;";
```

yourdbfile is `path+name` of your database file.

Comment: already i have given the connection know....Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","");

Comment: I already inserted username in database now i want to update the same database with agencyname and pid.This agencyname and pid are in the textbox.So i want to retrive the textbox value and update to the database...

Comment: I HAVE GIVEN LIKE THIS.......request.getParameter("agencyname");
            request.getParameter("pid");
            String name1=request.getParameter("name");
            int pid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pid"));
            String agencyname=request.getParameter("agencyname");
             Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:userdetail","","");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    st.executeUpdate("update userdetail set agency ='"+agencyname+"',pid='"+pid+"' where name='"+name1+"'");